# Automorphism on subgroup lift to the whole group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, characteristic-subgroups

By definition, if $H$ is characteristic subgroup of $G$, then every automorphism of $G$ restricted on $H$ is an automorphism of $H$.

From these two questions [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477524) [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478384) we know it's generally false that
if $H$ is characteristic subgroup of $G$, given $\varphi \in \text{Aut}(H)$, then there exists $\psi\in\text{Aut}(G)$ s.t. $\psi|_H=\varphi$. Example from $A_3$ and $S_3$ shows even if such a $\psi$ exists, it may not be unique.

**My question:**

Suppose $H$ is subgroup of $G$, what's the sufficient condition s.t. $\forall \varphi \in \text{Aut}(H)$, $\exists\ \psi\in\text{Aut}(G)$ s.t. $\psi|_H=\varphi$?

**Background:**

This question comes from studying $\text{Aut}(S_n)$ and $\text{Aut}(A_n)$.

If $n\geqslant 4$ and $n \neq 6$, then $\operatorname{Aut}(A_n)\cong\operatorname{Inn }(S_n)\cong\operatorname{Aut}(S_n)\cong S_n$.

The existence and uniqueness is true for $A_n$ and $S_n$($n\geqslant 4$ and $n \neq 6$), while uniqueness is not true for $A_3$ and $S_3$.

To move this question out of the unanswered list, I put related materials in answer.

Comment: See also this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477524/characteristic-subgroups-and-automorphisms

Comment: This seems extremely broad. What kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: It's an inverse problem for characteristic subgroup, and now that it's doesn't hold for $H$  just being characteristic subgroup of $G$, I wonder if there should be some restriction on subgroup $H$ of $G$, maybe index of $H$ in $G$ and center of $H$(like the $S_n$ and $A_n$ case), commutability of $H$, existing group $K$ s.t. $G \cong H\rtimes K$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related questions:

$1$. [Characteristic subgroups and automorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477524)

$2$. [Characteristic subgroups and automorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478384)

$3$. [Characterising extendable automorphisms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9749)

$4$. [Are the inner automorphisms the only ones that extend to every overgroup?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7782)

$5$. [Extensible automorphisms problem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Extensible_automorphisms_problem)